# How can I draw a line between 2 points in PCL?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to draw a line between 2 points in PCL, but I can't find examples for that.
I found addLine, but this requires x, y, z of one point as well as the line direction. I don't know how to get the line direction. I just have the coordinates of the 2 points.

Comment: Unrelated: avoid using tags where there is no tag wiki or usage information. Because `pcl` is not defined, odds are going to be high that `pcl` is being used as a dumping ground for many things that acronym to PCL in addition to point clouds and that few answerers involved in point clouds will be monitoring the tag.

Comment: I don't understand the question. addLine expects two points: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#aa788c98f62fbf379abfc3b03550ecab5